# Properties of triangles

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be an acute angle triangle in which $D,E,F$ are points on $BC,CA,AB$ such that $AD$ is perpendicular to $BC$,$AE=EC$ and $CF$ bisects angle $ACB$ internally. Suppose $CF$ meets $AD$ and $DE$ in $M$ and $N$ respectively . If $FM=2$, $MN=1cm$, $NC=3cm$ ...find perimeter of triangle $ABC$...

I am struggling to proceed and need help.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: what do you mean with $Nd$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that N is the midpoint of CF. This, together with E being the midpoint of AC, makes END // AFB. Further by intercept theorem, D is the midpoint of BC.

[image]

Then, AD is the perpendicular bisector of BC. This, in turn, means ABC is isosceles with AB = AC.

Let the centroid of ABC, formed by the intersection of the medians AD and BE, be at M’(say). Then, $\dfrac {CM’}{M’F’} = \dfrac {2}{1} = \dfrac {CM}{MF}$. Since this is impossible (unless MM' // PP'), we are left with CF being the third median.

All these yield the conclusion of ABC is equilateral with altitude = 6 cm.

The required perimeter can then be found through a 30-60-90 special angled triangle.